# Could the roots from an apple tree 10m away from my house be causing structural problems?

Tags: trees, roots, apples

I have a fairly large apple tree in my garden approximately 10m from my house. It stands about 8m high.

I have started getting cracks in my back 2 rooms and patio. is it likely to be the roots and if so, should I remove the tree?

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, the rootball is the same size as the branches. Do you have branches touching the house, or that would touch the house if you weren't cutting them back?

Answer (score 2):

That seems a little tall for an apple tree - if its not on a dwarfing rootstock, it should be kept pruned back. That said, it doesn't sound as if the apple tree is a likely culprit, though its not impossible. If you're on clay soil, then removing a tree can cause as many problems as it solves - take advice from a building surveyor.